# How do I find the longest word in a Visual Basic array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, cpu-word

I have an array in Visual Basic that needs to have the longest word returned. How do I go about locating the longest word in a String array? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim longestWord = String.Empty

For Each word in strArray
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(word) AndAlso word.Length > longestWord.Length Then
        longestWord = word
    End If        
Next
```

** *updated to account for null string* **

Answer (score 7):

A LINQ alternative is this:

```
Dim strings = New String() {"1", "02", "003", "0004", "00005"}

Dim longest As String = strings.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Length).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I'd propose doing a FirstOrDefault, otherwise it will crash if strings is empty.

Comment: @Scottie - If the string is empty, wouldn't Length be 0?

Comment: @KarlAnderson - What you had would have worked just fine.  An empty string will simply sort as 0 length.  Test it and you'll see.  The only reason you'd need `FirstOrDefault()` would be for a `null` string.

Comment: @Scott - sorry, I mistyped, `OrDefault` accounts for null, thanks for catching my typo. I cannot edit the comment, because it was posted too long ago.

Comment: @Scott - I meant if your string array is empty it will crash on First.  I make it a practice to use FirstOrDefault.

Comment: @Scottie - Oh you meant `strings` the variable name.  Gotcha.

Comment: It probably will not matter unless you do this many times a day with very large arrays, like researching 1000s of novels or something - But if you were... sorting the array first will at least take O(n * log n) time, but checking the length of each element as Scott shows should be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this... (It's c#, but should port to VB easily)

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
string longest = stringArray.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were to do this with Linq in C#, I would do it something like this:

```
var strings = new string[3] { "abc", "defg", "hijkl" };
string longest = strings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).FirstOrDefault();
```